# Next.js not auto refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm having trouble with Next.js, basically it doesn't auto refresh local host index page whenever I make a change.

I created a Next.js app using `npx create-next-app --use-npm`. I started the local server using `npm start`, then I edited the h1 tag in index.js file, changing it from  `<h1>First Page</h1>` to `<h1>Second Page</h1>`. Then I saved the file.

However, my local serve doesn't auto refresh and reflect the change I just made. I have to run `npm run build` then `npm run start` to be able to see the change.

Appreciate any suggestions, or maybe point me to the right direction on solving this, cuz not be able to see the auto refresh really slows down the dev process :(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use `npm run dev`

> These scripts refer to the different stages of developing an application:
>
> `dev` - Runs next dev which starts Next.js in development mode
>
> `build` - Runs next build which builds the application for production usage
>
> `start` - Runs next start which starts a Next.js production server

*source: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started*

Comment: It worked! I did further research and found I started the local server in production mode instead of dev mode. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it did. Please select as accepted answer then to give your question a closure ^^

Comment: thanks, it helped, i'm using yarn, so for me it will look like this: yarn dev

Answer (score 13):

make sure your import statement has the right casing

```
import Home from '../Components/home';

                vs

import Home from '../Components/Home';
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this to package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": " next dev -p 8000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
  }
```

then `npm run dev`

Comment: Thank you! Just checked my package.json, I got these lines :)

Answer (score 3):

Brother, I also had the same issue and tried the previous solutions in the previous answers. But as you said, hot reloading wasn't working when I made a change, and it wasn't showing any update in the localhost browser. It only showed the page where I started the server using `npm run dev`, not the changes I made after starting the server. (Hot reload didn't work only for changes made to my navbar.)

In my scenario, I named my file `Navbar.jsx` when I created a Navbar component, but I imported it into layout.js as `import Navbar from "./navbar/navbar";` . That was the issue. We have to reliably account for letter case. We have to use the same import statement as the file name for hot reloading to work in Next.js. So this is the correct way to import the file in my case `import Navbar from "./navbar/Navbar";`

Comment: this is exactly what my issue was, the file naming had an uppercase in the beginning, and i called the component below and it auto imported it, but the letters were in lower case, after i fixed it to uppercase it worked well. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Fast Refresh was broken for us because we were using a custom webpack config in our next.config.js that set React and ReactDOM as externals.

Ensuring both React and ReactDOM were included in the bundle while in local development fixed the issue for us.

```js
const isDev = NODE_ENV === 'development'

module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
    if (isDev) {
      return config;
    }

    return {
      ...config,
      externals: {
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
      },
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine was not working either.
My solution:

```
npm run build
npm start
```

It worked after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statement of that component, some times this error occurs due to naming convention where you are importing the component.

Comment: Since there is no solution proposed here with supporting evidence, this response is better suited as a comment

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing is just pay attention uppercase letters of the file while importing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35709415)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you have Auto Save enabled to False in your code editor.